# Right floated element dropping

Tags: html, css

In the following example the right hand div drops below the left. What is required to keep it from dropping?

Also note the order of the HTML must not change and the right div must maintain 250px while the left must fill remaining space.

```
<div id="left">
    Left
</div>    
<div id="right">
    Right
</div>

#left{
    margin-right: 250px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#right{
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k1cnt8qt/1/

Comment: Remove Margin-right in #left
http://jsfiddle.net/k1cnt8qt/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS table and table cell display can be used. Slight advantage is that the columns will be equal height and no clear fix is required.

```css
#wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#left {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: blue;
}
#right {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">Left</div>
    <div id="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

In case you are wondering why it is dropping, right floated element will align with the right side of the current line box, which starts below the left div. Moving the right floated div before left will also work.

Comment: Amazing how many other answers got submitted, when this is the correct way to fix it. One question for you Salman, is using table-row in there considered best practices even if its only one row?

Comment: Never used, never cared.

Answer (score 1):

It's breaking to the next line since #left isn't being floated.

```
#left {
    float: left;
    /* rest of css */
}
```

That said, you want it to take the full space, so you actually want columns here. Try this:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqzjeuja/)

html

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="left">
            Left - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor vestibulum accumsan. Nulla efficitur blandit imperdiet. Nunc in ante dolor. Duis malesuada aliquam eros non vestibulum. Quisque justo lorem, convallis a ante vel, placerat aliquam quam. Fusce sed erat rutrum, consectetur risus a, mollis lacus. Pellentesque finibus metus at arcu gravida tempor
        </div>    
        <div class="right">
            Right
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.table {
    display: table;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.left{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: blue;

}
.right{
    display:table-cell;
    width:250px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

This avoids negative margins, and also is pretty easily adaptable for any changes you might have.

Comment: Works perfectly, using table display does exactly what I expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
#left{

    float:left;
    background-color: blue;
    width:100%;
    margin-right:-250px;    


}
#right{

    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: orange;

}
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/k1cnt8qt/12/

Comment: Negative margins aren't necessary here, in which case this isn't the best answer. [See this for a discussion about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989930/using-css-negative-margins-a-good-or-bad-practice).

Comment: @charles the question is closed as *primarily **opinion-based*** :)

Answer (score 0):

left div has no width set so it stretches for 100% and applies right margin in the same line, making its inner width smaller, but outer still 100%. non floated element have 100% width if not specified otherwise in CSS (width, float, display inline/inline-block).

Answer (score 0):

just swap the right and left divs

```
<div id="right">
    Right
</div>
<div id="left">
    Left
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k1cnt8qt/3/

Comment: Did you notice "Also note the order of the HTML must not change"?

Comment: Obviously I did't. My bad.

Comment: But the styles can be switched, with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this the following way:

```
#left{

    background-color: blue;
    float:left;
    width:calc(100% - 250px);

}
#right{
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k1cnt8qt/13/

Answer (score -1):

```css
#left {
    background-color : blue;
    display : inline-block;
    width : 250px;
    padding-left : 5px;
}

#right {
    background-color : orange;
    display : inline-block;
    width : 250px;
    padding-left : 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "left">
    left
</div>
<div id = "right">
    right
</div>
```

Comment: He wanted #left to be the full width up to where right begins.